# Code is printing error though I am sure I did this right. What is wrong?

Tags: java, acs

Here's the code I have a question about:

```
package project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PostOffice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("User input: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        String[] determineinput = input.split(",");
        String regular = "Regular Postcard";
        String large = "Large Postcard";
        String envelope = "Envelope";
        String largeenvenlope = "Large Envelope";
        String packagee = "Package";
        String largepackage = "Large Package";
        String unmailable = "Unmailable";
        double height = Double.parseDouble(determineinput[0]);
        double length = Double.parseDouble(determineinput[1]);
        double thickness = Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2]);

        if (3.5 < height && height < 4.25) {
            if (3.5 < length && length < 6) {
                if (0.007 < thickness && thickness < 0.016) {
                    System.out.println(regular);
                }
            }
        } else if (4.25 < height && height < 6) {
            if (6 < length && length < 11.5) {
                if (0.007 < thickness && thickness < 0.016) {
                    System.out.println(large);
                }
            }
        } else if (3.5 < height && height < 6.125) {
            if (5 < length && length < 11.5) {
                if (0.25 < thickness && thickness < 0.5) {
                    System.out.println(envelope);
                }
            }
        } else if (6.125 < height && height < 24) {
            if (11 < length && length < 18) {
                if (0.25 < thickness && thickness < 0.5) {
                    System.out.println(largeenvenlope);
                }
            }
        } else if (height < 6.125 || height > 24) {
            if (length < 11 || length > 18) {
                if (thickness < 0.25 || thickness > 0.5) {
                    if ((height * 2 + length * 2) <= 84) {
                        System.out.println(packagee);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (height < 6.125 || height > 24) {
            if (length < 11 || length > 18) {
                if (thickness < 0.25 || thickness > 0.5) {
                    if ((height + length) > 84 && (height + length) < 130) {
                        System.out.println(largepackage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ((height < 3.5 || height > 24)
                && (thickness < 0.07 || thickness > 0.25)
                && (length < 3.5 || length > 18)) {
            System.out.println(unmailable);
        }
        System.out.println("Input doesn't match any result");
    }
}
```

When I run this particular code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found 
  at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
  at project.PostOffice.main(PostOffice.java:8)
```

What is wrong? I included the conditions to match the initialized variables and print that variable when the conditions return true. The system does print "User input:" but beneath it, the error pops up. I got rid of what could have become the problem but it doesn't change. I'm pretty sure I made the code pretty explicit and simple to read for the system but it keeps complaining. I see no other way of fixing this problem. Is it something with my for loops? Or is it something else?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with above code. How do you run it? From what I heard some editors like BlueJ have problems with properly handling System.in which may cause Scanner to not work correctly. If that is the case try using other editor/IDE or compile/run it via console manually.

Comment: What do you mean how do I run it? I use Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Make sure that the fle is actually saved and rebuild it.

Comment: What do you mean rebuild it? I've tried to but it's not working so I asked here.

Comment: If you run using Eclipse, make sure `Allocate console (necessary for input)` is checked on the `Common` tab of the `Run Configuration` used to execute the program.

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies, this should really go in the comments but my reputation isn't yet high enough for me to do that).

I have tried running your code on IntelliJ and it seems to work for me (I used inputs of 4, 4, 4.  Is your error coming up immediately after the User input line prints, or are you able to put in some figures first?  If the latter, what is your input?

Not related to your problem, but something which may make your code easier to read: Where a variable name is made of multiple words, try using camel case (capitalise the first letter in each word apart from the first, e.g. largeevelope becomes largeEnvelope).  I do like that you haven't used cryptically abbreviated names :)